# Update a cell with a value from another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to ask for your help writing a script to update a second sheet based on the first.

I have a sheet that I call "Base" that is updated every day and I have one that I call "Backup" that is only fed by new entries in the "Base" sheet.

The "Base" sheet feeds the "Backup" through a script that I created in which it searches A+D (these are the columns that I will concatenate) and if it matches the "Backup" sheet, it does not update that line, but if not matches, sends this line to the "Backup" sheet.

It turns out that A+D may be right but if the customer made a payment that is reflected in columns I and J I would like these values ​​to be updated in the "Backup" sheet without having to send a new line because this line is worked on and commented on in the "Backup" sheet.

The "Base" sheet is permanently deleted after the entire process has been carried out.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to copy values from the *base* sheet to the *backup* sheet if the *base* sheet has some data (*payment info*). If that is correct, then you can easily do so with Apps Script. Since you already have a script you only need to make small modifications.

First you want to read the *base* sheet and check if the relevant data is there or not. Here you can use [`Sheet.getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column) to check the specific cell that contains the data and [`Range.getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) to extract the data. Then you can check if the cell is empty or it contains the relevant data, and if it does you only need to paste it on the *backup* sheet with [`Range.setValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue). See the following example:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var base = SpreadsheetApp.openById('{ SHEET ID }').getSheetByName('My Sheet');
  var backup = SpreadsheetApp.openById('{ SHEET ID }').getSheetByName(
    'My Sheet');
  var paymentInfo1 = base.getRange(2, 9).getValue();
  var paymentInfo2 = base.getRange(2, 10).getValue();

  if (paymentInfo1 != '') {
    backup.getRange(2, 9).setValue(paymentInfo1);
  }
  
  if (paymentInfo2 != '') {
    backup.getRange(2, 10).setValue(paymentInfo2);
  }
}
```